# Hiding posts of some categories in index page in octopress?

Tags: jekyll, octopress, information-architecture

I have created a blog using octopress, I have made a dummy link instead of a page and pointed it to posts of some categories by editing the navigationbar  :

```
<ul class="main-navigation">
  <li><a href="{{ root_url }}/">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="{{ root_url }}/blog/archives">Archives</a></li>
  <li><a href="{{ root_url }}/about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="{{ root_url }}/blog/categories/python">Python101</a></li>
</ul>
```

The last link `Python101` will show posts from category python only.
Now I want to hide all the posts only from python category on the index page. You can see the live site here [bhansa.github.io](https://bhansa.github.io)

Is there any way I can do this?

**Update:** The above blog link is available no more.

Comment: Can you push your sources in source branch for better analysis ?

Comment: @DavidJacquel I have pushed the changes. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

Let's do it as an incremental answer :

Spec is : "**py101** *category posts must not appear in index*". You can exclude posts with py101 category but, you will end up with pagination showing an undetermined number of posts. User can get lost with a page with no post because you've posted 7 py101 posts in a row.

Alternative : **py101** is a collection. You make it available from

- the menu,
- the aside
- from inside posts referring to a new/updated collection item in py101

Comment: Good example :  10.000 links are part of the blog but I can't find them in the pagination. They are in the 10.000 category and in the archive. Why not in the blog pagination ?

Comment: may be he has changed the pagination, but the question is how I can hide those posts from my index page?